# fetchedObjects is nil after performFetch, but tableView has data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a working `UITableView` backed by `Core Data`.

I am now implementing a feature that when the table is empty, I disable the `rightBarButtonItem`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear: animated];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects ? YES : NO;
}
```

But even when the table has items, `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` returns nil, so the button is always disabled.

I call `performFetch` in `viewDidLoad`.

I tried this code inside viewDidLoad, but the same happens.

Why is `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` nil, even when the table is populated?

**EDIT** added more code

Items are generated immediately into a child context before showing the table. The same context is used for the `fetchRequest`.

The items are definitely in the context, since the table gets populated with the items in the child context. However, when calling `viewWillAppear`, `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` is still nil.

This is how I call `performFetch` (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
 NSError *error = nil;
 if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch: &error])
 {
      NSLog(@"Failed to perform fetch: %@", error);
 }

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
     });
    });
```

I am saving the context before showing the VC.

Comment: please add  code for fetching and nsmanagedObjectContext configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried calling `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` in your dispatchBlock like this

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
 NSError *error = nil;
 if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch: &error])
 {
      NSLog(@"Failed to perform fetch: %@", error);
 }

 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects ? YES : NO;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
     });
    });
```

Comment: Wow that works. There must be another reason that `fetchedObjects` gets deleted after showing the table.  I'll investigate.  Since the `performFetch` code is in a super class, and not all subclasses have the button, I will need to refactor my code a bit, but that should not be a problem. I am also checking for `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects.count` now, since `fetchedObjects` could exist but be empty.

Comment: The issue is you are fetching the data in async queue which will take some time and you are using `self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects` in viewWillAppear, may be at that time the result is not fetched

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that too. But still the table gets populated, so the delay must be very, very short. When I actually put the button enable code in `viewDidAppear`, it worked, but then first the view appeared, and then the button was dimmed, which doesn't look good. All works fine now.

Comment: Glad it helped :)